# Flutter Images load slow

Tags: flutter, dart

I have added a Video to visualize my problem better: https://streamable.com/wdhna2

The problem is that my images load slowly, even I added a precache method and a splash screen. On first boot, the problem isn't that big, maybe because of the precache.
here I'm implementing the precache method:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadImage(context);  <--- Method call
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
```

and here is my precache method (just a snipped, not for all pictures):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void loadImage(context){
  precacheImage(const AssetImage("assets/widgetsImages/bmi.jpg"), context);
  precacheImage(const AssetImage("assets/widgetsImages/calc.webp"), context);
  precacheImage(const AssetImage("assets/widgetsImages/chat.webp"), context);
}
```

I also tried to add a splash screen with the flutter_native_splash package, but this wouldn't fix the problem that the images load slowly after I close and reopen the app, without clearing my RAM. Anyway, here is the code for that:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
```

and the end of the splashscreen when the first window opens:

```
class _NutriWidgetState extends State<NutriWidget> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
  }
```

Do you have an idea how I could load the images faster? Do I do something wrong?

Comment: can you test on release mode?

Comment: The video is the release mode, so same problem

Comment: You could try adding an `Animation Controller` and handle the loading of the images with a transition. Maybe a fade-out and fade-in.

Comment: Good idea, I will try that out later!

Answer (score 1):

I'm maybe late to the party, but the usual way to handle this is to have a loading screen until you cache everything that you need on the main page of your app.

You are using the [precacheImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) function wrong, as it returns a Future, you should await the results. I suggest using [Future.wait](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html) to wait for multiple Futures to be completed.

You can use precacheImage without await, if you don't need the image(s) quickly. (~In the next few seconds.)

Unfortunately, image handling is a bit *weird* in Flutter, so you have to use this workaround. Also, try to update to Flutter 3.10, it contains a few small image-loading performance fixes.

Answer (score 0):

try
image.assets("assets/widgetsImages/bmi.jpg")

Comment: you mean inside the loadImage function? This dont work, it says: The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'.

Answer (score 0):

think you can not call directly into the widget builder
you have to wrap it into Scaffolds

or return your method not call this

**return** loadImage(context)